# Designing GUI in WPF as easy as Winforms?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am familiar with Winforms GUI design: drag and drop controls on to the form, write code for the events, etc.

Using VS2010 is creating a WPF app this easy?

Comment: Define easy and this question might survive.

Answer (score 2):

Learning XAML is a fairly involved.

stopping using code behind and events from your gui and going to MVVM is an eye opener.

So, if you find winform gui coding "natural", then going to wpf is not going to be overly easy.

It is however IMO well worth it.  MVVM gives amazing benefits in terms of simplifying and reducing code.
If you need your controls to do something out of the norm, then XAML and styles are great for customizing your gui.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very easy once you have some experience with WPF.  Like anything you'll need to get used to it, and learn the tricks.

For quick, simple, single form projects I think winforms will always be faster and easiest.

Comment: Do you need to use Expression, or will VS be fine?

Comment: if you write xaml by hand you can use vs2010. if you want drag&drop and stuff use blend :) the designer for vs2010 is not as bad as vs2008 but the designer adds margins and stuff and this sucks.

Comment: @blindmeis - Just right-click the control and reset the margins/sizes/whatever :)